# Loop through array of input objects

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have these HTML objects:

```
<button id="addMore" class="button">+</button>

<div id="fieldList">
    <input type="text" name="gsm[]" placeholder="GSM" required>
    <input type="text" name="gsm[]" placeholder="GSM" required>
    <input type="text" name="gsm[]" placeholder="GSM" required>
</div>
```

Now I want to loop through each one of them in JavaScript. Each of the input text has different values. This is what I have tried (the current code is a small snippet of a bigger code):

```
$('input[name^="gsm"]').each(function(i,obj) {  
        var eachGsm = $(this).val();
        
        "This line has " + eachGsm[i] + ", as the value." + "%0D%0A" +
    });
```

When running this, the script gives me: `[object Object]`. What is the correct approach?

Comment: `eachGsm` isn't an array , on your `each` loop `eachGsm` contains your input type text value, if you want an array you have to create it and push the values inside

Answer (score 1):

You're already iterating over the list of elements, therefore `this` is already your desired value.

```
<button id="addMore" class="button">+</button>

<div id="fieldList">
    <input type="text" name="gsm[]" placeholder="GSM" value='1' required>
    <input type="text" name="gsm[]" placeholder="GSM"  value='2' required>
    <input type="text" name="gsm[]" placeholder="GSM" value='3' required>
</div>
```

```
$('document').ready(()=>{
  $('input[name^="gsm"]').each(function(i,obj) {  
        var eachGsm = $(this).val();
         console.log("each: " + eachGsm);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can simply do

```js
$('input[name^="gsm"]').each(function(i) {          
    console.log("This line has " + this.value + ", as the value." + "%0D%0A")
});
```

In the context of this function, `this` is the object referring to the HTML `input` element, and `this.value` is the text content entered by the user.

A runnable example:
https://jsfiddle.net/23ao7mup/1/